# How to create a new TextView in another activity when I press the button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a new TextView every time my button is pressed in the `AgendaActivity`, but I can't figure it out. I read something about bundle but I am confused. Could you please help me? Thanks!
P.S: In the `AgendaActivity` is just an empty linear layout.

Java:

```
package com.exemple.android.calendar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewEventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //step 1.A:create objects

    public EditText DayEditText;
    public EditText MonthEditText;
    public EditText YearEditText;
    public EditText StartingHourEditText;
    public EditText StartingMinuteEditText;
    public EditText EndingHourEditText;
    public EditText EndingMinuteEditText;
    public EditText Title;
    public RadioGroup answer1;
    public Button NewEventButton;

    int day, month, year, s_hour, s_min, e_hour, e_min;
    String title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_event_page);

        //Step 1.B: assign objects

        DayEditText = findViewById(R.id.DayEditText);
        MonthEditText = findViewById(R.id.MonthEditText);
        YearEditText = findViewById(R.id.YearEditText);
        StartingHourEditText = findViewById(R.id.StartingHourEditText);
        StartingMinuteEditText = findViewById(R.id.StartingMinuteEditText);
        EndingHourEditText = findViewById(R.id.EndingHourEditText);
        EndingMinuteEditText = findViewById(R.id.EndingMinuteEditText);
        Title = findViewById(R.id.TitleEditText);
        answer1 = findViewById(R.id.Answer1);
        NewEventButton = findViewById(R.id.CreateEventButton);

        DayEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "31")});
        MonthEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "12")});
        YearEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "2030")});
        StartingHourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "24")});
        StartingMinuteEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "59")});
        EndingHourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "24")});
        EndingMinuteEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "59")});
        //Step 2: get data into variables

        //Step 2.B: get data and assign
        //PROBLEM: If we just extract, the code won't be run because there's nothing to extract yet. We need a conditional.
        //SOLUTION: Create a condition for pressing the button, and then extract the variables when the button is pressed.

        TextWatcher dayTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                day = Integer.parseInt(DayEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher monthTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                month = Integer.parseInt(MonthEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher yearTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                year = Integer.parseInt(YearEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher titleTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                title = Title.getText().toString();
            }
        };
        TextWatcher s_hourTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                s_hour = Integer.parseInt(StartingHourEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher s_minTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                s_min = Integer.parseInt(StartingMinuteEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher e_minTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                e_min = Integer.parseInt(EndingMinuteEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher e_hourTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                e_hour = Integer.parseInt(EndingHourEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };

        DayEditText.addTextChangedListener(dayTextWatcher);
        MonthEditText.addTextChangedListener(monthTextWatcher);
        YearEditText.addTextChangedListener(yearTextWatcher);
        Title.addTextChangedListener(titleTextWatcher);
        StartingMinuteEditText.addTextChangedListener(s_minTextWatcher);
        StartingHourEditText.addTextChangedListener(s_hourTextWatcher);
        EndingMinuteEditText.addTextChangedListener(e_minTextWatcher);
        EndingHourEditText.addTextChangedListener(e_hourTextWatcher);

        NewEventButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                answer1.clearCheck();
                Intent agendaPageGoing = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AgendaActivity.class);
                startActivity(agendaPageGoing);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

P.P.S: The app is a calendar. When I press the button it should create a new TextView with the data, but I will put the details in it later. Just help me with this task if you can.

Comment: You want to create Textviews during runtime?

Comment: Yep. I want every time the button is pressed to create a new TextView with some details (day, month, title, etc.). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Linear or Relative Layout
2. onCreate

   ```
   RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rLayout);

   final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[20];
   int i = 0;
   ```
3. On Button click

   ```
   final TextView tempTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

   tempTextView.setText("Display Text");
   myTextViews[i] = tempTextView;
   rLayout.addView(myTextViews[i]);
   i++;
   ```

Comment: Yeah, nice try. I've done it too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: First, yes. Second, it is not what I hoped to do. I don't want just one TextView. I want a new TextView every time the button is pressed.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. FIRST PROBLEM: when I declare the tempTextView, the context field ("this") doesn't work. SECOND PROBLEM: LayoutParams isn't working too. Any ideas?

Comment: PS: Thanks anyway, the array idea is genius.

Comment: I've updated my answer again, please do check. I hope it works.